# Circular Dependency with forward declaration error

Tags: c++

In A.hpp file I have a structure, which has a pointer of B class

```
struct state
{
    B  *b;
};
```

In A.hpp file, I added a forward declaration and I included B.hpp file in A.cpp file

```
//A.hpp
class B
```

In B.hpp file, a function uses the state, which declared in A.hpp as an argument on the function.

```
bool function_in_b(state *s)
```

I also added a forward declaration of A in B.hpp file and I added the header file of A, A.hpp in B.cpp file.

```
//B.hpp
class A
```

All header files have a header guard. If I try to compile, it won't find 'state' declared in A.hpp. Thus, it won't find the matching function and complains the candidates are

```
bool function_in_b(int *)
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Which file are you trying to compile when you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `B.hpp`, you say you forward-declared `A`, but not `state` - so when it first sees `function_in_b(state *s)` it doesn't know what `state` is. By the time you include `A.hpp` in `B.cpp` it's too late. You need to forward declare `state` in `B.hpp`, i.e.

```
struct state;

bool function_in_b(state *s);
```

Answer (score 1):

In B.hpp file, before the declaration of `function_in_b(state *)`, forward declare the `state` type:

```
struct state;
```