# Ahead definition of class in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circular Dependency with forward declaration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114078/circular-dependency-with-forward-declaration-error)

I have two files, one that defines structs (here: ports) and another one that defines a class (here: device). Since the class uses these structs as ports, they in return need to be linked to the class, preferably by a pointer. But how do I create this pointer if the device class has not been defined?

This is roughly what I want the code to look like...

backbone.h:

```
typedef struct aPort {
    std::string portName;
    Device *ptrDeviceThatOwnsPort;
} port;
```

device.h:

```
#include "backbone.h"

class Device {
}
```

...but this obviously will throw an error in backbone.h saying that *Device has not been defined*. I tried simply including the device header in the backbone header file, in front of the typedef, but that didn't work because each header is dependent upon another. Somewhere I have read, that in Objectve-C there is something along the lines of an "ahead class definition" or so (haven't coded in Obj-C for quite some time), so is there something similar in C++? Or is there an even better solution to my problem?

Any help is very welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: From other threads I've read, I think you just need to add the 'class' keyword before the word 'Device' in backbone.h

Comment: This has tons of duplicates, I just added one possiblility.

Comment: That is right. It's called forward-declaration and I found the term literally two minutes after posting this question. So sorry for this, but many thanks for the answers =]

Comment: Saying `throw an error` make it sounds like a runtime problem, when actually it's a compilation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use forward-declaration.

```
class Device;

typedef struct aPort {
    std::string portName;
    Device *ptrDeviceThatOwnsPort;
} port;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a forward declaration of Device. To do this, modify your "backbone.h" file to be the following:

```
class Device;
typedef struct aPort {
    std::string portName;
    Device *ptrDeviceThatOwnsPort;
} port;
```

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

As your struct just has a pointer to `Device` you can get aware with forward declaring the class. Just add

```
 class Device;
```

before your declaration of `aPort` in its header file. If you were not using a pointer, you would be required to include the header file of `Device`

Answer (score 1):

In backbone.h. add

```
class Device;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously because bythe time the compiler reaches the line

```
Device *ptrDeviceThatOwnsPort;
```

it doesn't know what `Device` is. However, you don't need to include the `Device`'s header at this point. Since you are making a pointer, it will be enough for the compiler to know that `Device` is a class name. By adding a forward declaration which looks like

```
class Device;
```

in front, you will let the compiler know it, and it will be able to make that pointer.